# Grounding wire for ceiling pendant

Tags: ceiling

I am trying to install a metal light pendant with a ground wire, it is replacing a plastic pendant which has no metal box or grounding nut, do I just connect the ground wire to the earth along with the earth of the pendant, thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not a metal box up there, yes, just connect the ground wire from your new light fixture to the ground wire coming in with the feed wires. Use the appropriate wire connector.